# Unable to get table <td> text values using python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the table text values from a `td` tag, but I always get an empty list.

Here is the [link](https://www.international-pc.com/product/interfine-629) from where I'm trying to extract table values.

Here is what I have tried.

```
response = requests.get('https://www.international-pc.com/product/interfine-629')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find("table", {"id": "documentTable-1"}).find_all("tbody")
print(tables)
Output :  []
```

the HTML

```
<table id="documentTable-1" class="display dataTable no-footer" data-table="" role="grid" aria-describedby="documentTable-1_info" style="width: 1138px;">
          <thead>
            <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="documentTable-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 391px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="PRODUCT DATASHEET: activate to sort column descending">PRODUCT DATASHEET</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="documentTable-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 455px;" aria-label="LANGUAGE: activate to sort column ascending">LANGUAGE</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="documentTable-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 232px;" aria-label="DOWNLOAD: activate to sort column ascending">DOWNLOAD</th></tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">Interfine 629</td><td>English (United Kingdom)</td><td><a href="https://international.brand.akzonobel.com/m/1ff7b0196600886b/original/Interfine_629_eng_A4_20151012.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">Interfine 629</td><td>Korean (Korea, Republic of)</td><td><a href="https://international.brand.akzonobel.com/m/664b77540ff01960/original/Interfine_629_kor_A4_19000101.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">Interfine 629</td><td>Chinese (China)</td><td><a href="https://international.brand.akzonobel.com/m/6980eb615ebe99f0/original/Interfine_629_chi_s_A4_20150205.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I want to extract all three rows text values from the table .

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://www.international-pc.com/product/interfine-629` website link is dynamic rendering request `table data`. You should try automation `selenium` library. it allows you to **scrape** dynamic rendering request(js or ajax) page data.

**Try this:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.international-pc.com/product/interfine-629')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

tables = soup.find("table", {"id": "documentTable-1"}).find("tbody")

for tr in tables.find_all("tr"):
    for td in tr.find_all("td"):
        print(td.text)
        link = td.find("a",href=True)

        if link is None:
            continue
        print(link['href'])
```

O/P:

```
 Interfine 629
Chinese (China)
PDF
https://international.brand.akzonobel.com/m/6980eb615ebe99f0/original/Interfine_629_chi_s_A4_20150205.pdf
Interfine 629
Korean (Korea, Republic of)
PDF
https://international.brand.akzonobel.com/m/664b77540ff01960/original/Interfine_629_kor_A4_19000101.pdf
Interfine 629
English (United Kingdom)
PDF
https://international.brand.akzonobel.com/m/1ff7b0196600886b/original/Interfine_629_eng_A4_20151012.pdf
```

where `'/usr/bin/chromedriver'` selenium web driver path.

**Download selenium web driver for chrome browser:**

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

**Install web driver for chrome browser:**

https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/

**Selenium tutorial:**

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: if I want to extract <a href> text for `PDF` text , how do I get that.. because when I do `tr[0]['href']` it gives `KeyError`

Comment: With respect to the same question.how can we extract same thing if there are multiple pages under `SDS` tab? here is the link  https://www.international-pc.com/product/interfine-629

Comment: @deepesh please ask a question in a new thread with your problems.

Answer (score 0):

you could also just go straight to the data source without using Selenium:

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://www.international-pc.com/get/ajax/2305/TDS'


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}

params = {
'draw':'1',
'columns[0][data]':'PRODUCT DATASHEET',
'columns[0][name]':'',
'columns[0][searchable]':'true',
'columns[0][orderable]':'true',
'columns[0][search][value]':'',
'columns[0][search][regex]':'false',
'columns[1][data]':'LANGUAGE',
'columns[1][name]':'',
'columns[1][searchable]':'true',
'columns[1][orderable]':'true',
'columns[1][search][value]':'',
'columns[1][search][regex]':'false',
'columns[2][data]':'DOWNLOAD',
'columns[2][name]':'',
'columns[2][searchable]':'true',
'columns[2][orderable]':'true',
'columns[2][search][value]':'',
'columns[2][search][regex]':'false',
'order[0][column]':'0',
'order[0][dir]':'asc',
'start':'0',
'length':'10',
'search[value]':'',
'search[regex]':'false'}


data = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=params).json()
df = json_normalize(data['data'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                                            DOWNLOAD  ... PRODUCT DATASHEET
0  <a href="https://international.brand.akzonobel...  ...     Interfine 629
1  <a href="https://international.brand.akzonobel...  ...     Interfine 629
2  <a href="https://international.brand.akzonobel...  ...     Interfine 629

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: How to add other values, If I want to do this same task for other table under `SDS` tab, which has 4 columns..

Comment: you'd have to look/play around with those parameters. I won;t be able to look at it until Sunday though

Comment: I didn't understand how you created the json format for `params` .